# Numpy split array centered around the centroid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I would like to split a 3D array of size (101, 151, 101) into sub-arrays of say size (21, 21, 21). (Sizes are not fixed, but, odd numbers for ease). The only requirement is, the splitting should be done from the middle. So, the midpoint of the original matrix should be in the middle of a subarray, so that the blocks are distributed evenly across the original matrix.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried numpy split, but it starts from the beginning of the matrix.

Comment: The numbers you state are all not dividable by 21, how do you want to handle that?

Comment: There are two issues - figuring out where the splits should occur, and actually slicing the array and collected those in some sort of list (or nested lists).  Surely you can figure out, for yourself, the split locations!  Sounds like there are too  many decision details for some off-the-shelf function.

Comment: Pretty straight forward if the dimensions multiples of your sub-arrays: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: @joe, The dimensions will not be multiples of the sub-arrays. Ideal case, create unequal subarrays around the edges of the original matrix. But, if this is too complex, discard the edge values .

Comment: Start with a 1d array

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Start simple. If you got it working for a single dimension you are already there. First check the dimensions of your array and get the index of the center element. Then find out how many slice you like and calculate their indices starting from the center.

Answer (score 0):

I created a code that can do this for a 2D matrix which can be easily adapted for a 3D matrix. I guess this can be modified make it more efficient.

```
image_size = (15, 19)
mid_point = (7, 9)
block_size = (3, 3)

## Identification of the starting point of mid points. 
d0_point = mid_point[0]
while (d0_point - (block_size[0]-1)/2) > -1:
    d0_point = d0_point - block_size[0]
d0_point = d0_point + block_size[0]

d1_point = mid_point[1]
while (d1_point - (block_size[1]-1)/2) > -1:
    d1_point = d1_point - block_size[1]
d1_point = d1_point + block_size[1]

i_points = (d0_point, d1_point)

## Calculating number of blocks in the matrix
block_array = numpy.zeros(image_size, dtype=int)
n0 = int((image_size[0] - (d0_point - (block_size[0]-1)/2)*2)/block_size[0] )
n1 = int((image_size[1] - (d1_point - (block_size[1]-1)/2)*2)/block_size[1] )

block_count = (n0, n1)

## List of mid-points of blocks
eye_list = []
for ni in range(n0):
    for nj in range(n1):
        eye_list.append((ni*block_size[0]+d0_point, nj*block_size[1]+d1_point))

## Marking blocks.             
block_number = 1
for eye in eye_list:
    block_array[int(eye[0]-(block_size[0]-1)/2):int(eye[0]-(block_size[0]-1)/2)+block_size[0], 
            int(eye[1]-(block_size[1]-1)/2):int(eye[1]-(block_size[1]-1)/2)+block_size[1]] = block_number
    block_number += 1
```